# Command line copy all network folder files of a specific name pattern including those files in subfolders

Tags: cmd, grep, copy, findstr

I want to use command line to copy all files from a network folder to my local machine.

I only want to copy files that have a specific name string pattern.

The files may be located in different folders or subfolders.

For example, if we have the following files:

```
//networkfolder/subfolder1/213123_Hello_212131.txt
//networkfolder/subfolder2/41241_Hello21312312.txt
//networkfolder/subfolder3/23_12122112Hello.txt
```

I want to be able to copy the files that have the string pattern "Hello".

Comment: so whats the issue? what have you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a possible solution:

```bat
FOR /R \\networkfolder\ %%A IN (*Hello*) DO command
```

Should work for you. You can search more about the `for /R` loop.